# libvlc удаление MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, vlc

Может кто использовал библиотеку libvlc. Проблема в том что когда пытаюсь уничтожить объект класса MediaPlayer то все напрочь зависает минуты на две, после чего объект уничтожается.
Инициализирую плеер следующим образом:

```
private void play(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();

    libVLC = new LibVLC(context, args);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);
    mediaPlayer.setEventListener(eventListener);

    vlcVout = mediaPlayer.getVLCVout();

    vlcVout.setVideoSurface(surfaceTexture);

    Media media = new Media(libVLC, Uri.parse(url));

    media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, true);

    mediaPlayer.setMedia(media);

    media.release();

    vlcVout.attachViews();
    mediaPlayer.play();

}
```

Пытаюсь уничтожить следующим образом

```
public void release() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && libVLC != null) {
        pause();
        libVLC.release();
        libVLC = null;
        mediaPlayer.setEventListener(null);
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        }
}
```

Здесь начинаются проблемы на строчке `mediaPlayer.release();` Может кто встречался с такой проблемой и знает как решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в либе, использовал версию 2.0.6.  вот здесь есть обсуждение по этому поводу https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk/issues/74 . Я в итоге стал использовать версию 1.9.8 и все прошло.